# What external context could cause splice to not do anything?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, electron

I have this splice line, with a debug line either side:

```
const obj = { x:[1,2], y:{t:"!!!"} }
const lenBefore = S.groupings.length
const ret = S.groupings.splice(gix, 0, obj)
console.log(`${lenBefore} --> ${S.groupings.length}, gix=${gix}, ret=${JSON.stringify(ret)}`)
```

It gives this output, which I believe is impossible:

```
3 --> 3, gix=2, ret=[]
```

I.e. the `splice` did not add or remove anything.

Another run, on different data, gave:

```
18 --> 18, gix=2, ret=[]
```

This function is fairly complex, but I have some unit tests to cover the main ways it is used. I left the `console.log()` lines in when running them, and those tests give me:

```
1 --> 2, gix=0, ret=[]
3 --> 4, gix=1, ret=[]
```

I.e. exactly what I'd expect. So, something about the environment when run for real is causing this.

(It is an electron app, this code is running in the front-end part, i.e. effectively in Chrome, and it is with Chrome developer tools that I'm looking at the console. The unit tests are running in mocha 3.2.0, node 6.11.4. The real environment is Electron 1.8.1, which is Chrome 59, i.e. slightly newer.)

Has anyone any idea what external context could possibly cause `splice()` to not do its job?

**UPDATE:**

If I instead use this, then everything works both in the live code and in the unit tests:

```
S.groupings = S.groupings.slice(0,gix).concat(obj, S.groupings.slice(gix))
```

There is obviously something about `S.groupings` that stops it being mutated, but just in my complex live code, not in a unit test! That in itself is quite interesting, as I thought it was not possible to make immutable javascript objects...

BTW, the following code:

```
console.log(`S type=${typeof S}; isArray=`+ Array.isArray(S))
console.log(`S.groupings type=${typeof S.groupings}; isArray=`+ Array.isArray(S.groupings))
```

tells me identical results in live and unit test code:

```
S type=object; isArray=false
S.groupings type=object; isArray=true
```

And I also tried this, near the top of the function:

```
S.groupings = Array.from(S.groupings)
```

It made no difference. I.e. all the evidence points to that `S.groupings` is just a normal JavaScript array.

**UPDATE 2:** Not frozen or sealed:

```
Object.isFrozen(S.groupings)  //false
Object.isSealed(S.groupings)  //false
Object.isExtensible(S.groupings)  //true
```

---

By the way, to try to narrow it down I made the following three, increasingly complex, simplifications of the real code, as mocha tests. They all pass perfectly. Of course they do. I decided to include it here, as it gives you more context than the one line I posted above, and also shows some things that are obviously *not* the explanation.

```
it("1", function(){
const S = {
  groupings:[ {a:1,b:2}, {a:2,b:"xxx"}, {a:3,b:false} ],
  tom:"hello",
  dick:[1,2,3],
  harry:null
}

const obj = {a:2.5, b:"INSERT ME"}
let gix = 2

assert.equal(S.groupings.length, 3)

S.groupings.splice(gix, 0, obj)

assert.equal(S.groupings.length, 4)

})

//--------------------------------

it("2", function(){
const S = {
  groupings:[ {a:1,b:2}, {a:2,b:"xxx"}, {a:3,b:false} ],
  tom:"hello",
  dick:[1,2,3],
  harry:null
}

const CG = [ {z:1}, {z:2}, {z:3} ]

const obj = {a:2.5, b:"INSERT ME"}

for(let gix = 0;gix < CG.length; ++gix){
  const g = CG[gix]
  if(g.z < obj.a)continue
  assert.equal(S.groupings.length, 3)
  S.groupings.splice(gix, 0, obj)
  assert.equal(S.groupings.length, 4)
  break
}
})

//--------------------------------

it("3", function(){
const data = {
  "1":{},
  "2":{
  groupings:[ {a:1,b:2}, {a:2,b:"xxx"}, {a:3,b:false} ],
  tom:"hello",
  dick:[1,2,3],
  harry:null
}}

const CG_outer = [ {z:1}, {z:2}, {z:3} ]

function inner(CG, txt){
  const S = data["2"]
  const obj = {a:2.5, b:txt}

  for(let gix = 0;gix < CG.length; ++gix){
    const g = CG[gix]
    if(g.z < obj.a)continue
    assert.equal(S.groupings.length, 3)
    S.groupings.splice(gix, 0, obj)
    assert.equal(S.groupings.length, 4)
    break
  }
}

inner(CG_outer, "INSERT ME")
assert.deepEqual(data["2"].groupings,
  [ {a:1,b:2}, {a:2,b:"xxx"}, {a:2.5, b:"INSERT ME"}, {a:3,b:false} ] )
})
```

Comment: `S.groupings = Object.freeze([…])`?

Comment: @Bergi Good guess - I think that could have caused these symptoms. But I just updated my question to show it is not frozen. I did (kind of) work out what was going on, see my self-answer.

Comment: Actually I think a frozen object would have thrown an exception. It would need to have been an array whose `length` property was overwritten not to change.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally tracked it down. Electron apps have distinct back-end/front-end processes, with message parsing. I was doing this:

```
S = mainProcess.getLatestData(...)
```

If I change that to:

```
const ret = mainProcess.getLatestData(...)
Object.assign(S, ret)
```

then everything, including `splice()` works as expected.

I cannot really explain what is going on, though. `ret` is not frozen, sealed, and is extensible. It appears to be a plain JS object in all respects, and `ret.groupings` to be a simple JS array.

And `S` was originally data that came from the front-end. (However that was sent in an event from the front-end, rather than requested, and those are two different mechanisms in Electron.)